# PHP handle incoming CURL requests from same origin as separate

Tags: php, multithreading, curl, multiprocessing, php-curl

I have website1 and website2, each website with its own webserver, each using Apache MPM and PHP, latest versions.

Visitors from website1 send a POST request to website1 and then website1 communicates with website2, via cURL and passes some data to it and then waits for a response.

Website1 code sample:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'https://www.website.com?request='.$enc_data);

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS ,30000); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 30000); //timeout in seconds

$result = curl_exec($ch);   
//log the result to database
curl_close($ch);
```

Website 2 does some operations that take around 1 second to be executed. So each time the response time is over 1 second. Sometimes it is even 2-3 seconds.

Sample code for website2 (for simulation purposes)

```
sleep(mt_rand(1,3)); 
echo 'Request solved';
```

The problem is that if 100 requests come from website1 via the code above, towards website2, they are executed one by one (FIFO) and not in parallel. Meaning that after the 30th request, everything times-out.

Problem is that these requests are done on a constant basis and their number can increase and I need website2 to be able to process them in parallel somehow. I cannot accept continuous time outs. The server can be upgraded to have more resources, that is not the issue.

Like on any dynamic server, if 100 people send a request from their browsers to website1 (by clicking a button or refreshing the website) then that request is processed separately by website1, without adding delays to any of the other 99 people when someone will access any page from website1, because I assume that Apache assigns each request to a thread/worker.

I want the same for website2 to process the requests coming from website1, to basically handle each request as a different "requester" and handle it in parallel.

I am assuming that this may be an apache setting or something that I need to add to the headers in the cURL request, so that website2 will think that the request comes from a different IP/visitor or something like that.

Can anybody guide me how to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 1):

**Regarding the problem:**

> The problem is that if 100 requests come from website1 via the code
>   above, towards website2, they are executed one by one (FIFO) and not
>   in parallel. Meaning that after the 30th request, everything
>   times-out.

If on server2 runs apache then why should website2 execute the it one by one and not parallel? cURL access website2 same way like a browser does.

*That the requests get executed one by one is definitely not true.*

**Apache:**

Apache delivers a standard config and this config does not contains so small limits. However you can increase the settings:

```
    StartServers              5
    MinSpareServers           5
    MaxSpareServers          10
    MaxRequestWorkers         150
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
```

More information regarding this - maybe this helps you:
https://serverfault.com/questions/775855/how-to-configure-apache-workers-for-maximum-concurrency

On your place i would also turn off the Keepalive in the Apache2 config to not waste connections:

```
    KeepAlive Off
```

**cURL:**

i would even turn off keepalive on the curl site using CURL_OPT_HTTPHEADER:

```
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Connection: Close'
));
```

And forbid cURL to reuse connections by using - i it should also helps to avoid blocking:

```
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, TRUE);
```

Another setting is to avoid (sometimes ocurring) long waiting time when cURL cant resolve ipv4 and retry to resolve IPv6 (which is not configured or wrong).

```
curl_setopt($curlHandle,  CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
```

There are many other options to tune your speed. Sending data from one server to another is not such a nice solution in generally and its absolutely normal that it prolong the execution time of your script. But that you receive timeouts is not normal. Tweak your settings as written above and it should solve it - the problem is more on the Server2 Apache config than on the cURL side.